# Sunspot search results not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

post.rb

```
 ...
  searchable do
    text :title, :description
    string :category
    time :created_at
    integer :post_id
  end
 ...
```

post_controller.rb

```
@search = Post.search do
  fulltext params[:q]
  with(:created_at).less_than Time.zone.now
end
```

The above code works correctly, but when I try to scope by post_id or category, I get no results.

So, something like

```
with(:category).equal_to("category_name")
```

or

```
with :post_id, 1
```

Shows no results, and thus does not work correctly.
Any ideas on how to debug sunspot solr?  I've been to :8982/solr/admin and checked the development logs, but I can't figure out what would be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added search fields but have you reindexed your data? Try calling in console:

```
RAILS_ENV=yours_env rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

AFAIK this is proper behaviour of solr with added new fields but without reindexing (fields are empty so there are no results but also no 'loud' error).

Comment: I thought I had reindexed but I hadn't!  This was it.